# using greater than in function line in r

Tags: r

I am trying to do a subset within a function and it is not working out the way I was hoping.  Here is the code I am actually trying to run:

```
plot.by = function(output, plot.warming, plot.baseline, apply.dim, attribute, selection){

    par(mfrow= c(3,3))

    for(site in 1:length(output)){
    zero = apply(get(output[site])[,,attribute], c(1), sum)/32

    zero = zero[selection]
    zero = as.data.frame(zero) 
    zero = rownames(zero)
        two = get(plot.warming[site])[zero,,,]
        zero = get(plot.baseline[site])[zero,,,]


    boxplot(apply(two, apply.dim, mean) - apply(zero, apply.dim, mean), ylim = c(-200,300))
    }
}

plot.by(output= data.zero, plot.warming= aet.two, plot.baseline = aet.zero, apply.dim = c(1,3), attribute= "snowpack", selection= zero>2000)
```

and here is my example to play with:

```
select.by.attribute = function(data, selection){
    tmp = data[selection]
    plot(tmp)
}

select.by.attribute(data=data, selection= data>100)
```

I know that the example function works, however I believe it only works because it does the selection before the function is even run.  If I run my actual code with a clean workspace it says "zero" is not found.  If at all possible I would like the selection= >1000 rather than having the object in there.

In addition, any suggestion on how to search for this stuff in the future or an information source would be great. For example I don't even know what the line is called to "call" the function or the different attributes- made searching for the question quite difficult.

To add more information to what I am trying to do.  My data is from a hydrological model where the outputs are daily measurements of things like snowfall, precipitation, evaporation, etc.  In the end I am trying to plot data from these sites based upon certain attributes such as precip>2000.  So to do this I first need to apply over some attribute, then I subset those specific row names (which are the site names), and then I plot those sites at the bottom (the plot(apply is to collapse 4 dimensions into two to plot them).

Essentially I need to do this a lot of times- so I want to be able to quickly do this for whatever attribute I want, whether that be precipitation or snowfall, as well as a selection to be >2000 or whatever number.  Hence why I tried the make the function.

Comment: You passed the condition to the function (`zero > 2000`), but not the actual data. You can add a new variable to the function, say `data`, call with `data=zero` and use `data[selection]` inside the function. But unless you'll also use the full data, you can simply pass the subset with `data=zero[zero>2000]`and remove the subsetting from the function body.

Comment: Molx- thanks for responding.  The only problem is, if I am understanding you correctly, that I am subsetting not based upon the data but a mean of one attribute in the data.  Ill go back no and edit the post to describe this a little more.

Comment: I read your code again and realized I got confused because you call `output` the input data of your function. Anyway, I think that you should simply pass the threshold value in `selection` e.g. `selection=2000`, and then use `zero <- zero[zero<selection]`. That's because when calling the function you don't know `zero` yet, so you can't compare it to anything.

Comment: Sorry, that is confusing out of context.  This is one module in a larger function, but I should probably call it something different.  Your solution is great, however I need to take it a little further.  I truly want to be able to change the > and < and if possible I would like the options to be >, <, or < and >.  Any ideas?  Could I do something like an if statement and prompt which one I use in the command line?